# How to write a wrapper function for cout in order to control it by just passing command line arguments?

Tags: c++, command-line-arguments, cout

My aim is to get two forms of output from the program, one with all the print statements that will come into action and the other is the program will operate but there will be no print output. I can do this by writing two different codes, one with `cout` and other with out it. But I want to create a function that does the job in a single code. It will check for particular command line argument. If true, then cout or else nothing. In this way without editing the code, just by passing additional arguments I can control whether to print anything or not.

I am unable to do anything like that!

Comment: Why the "C" tag? Please read tags' descriptions before applying them! That said, you can pass in an `ostream&` into a function where it can write stuff. Whether that ends up anywhere can then be controlled by supplying different argumenst, like e.g. `cout`, but also `cerr` or other streams, including ones that don't write anywhere.

Comment: You don't need to check for a particular command line argument, use `./program` to show the output or `./program 1>/dev/null` to hide it.

Comment: The shell _should_ allow you to run the program from the command line redirecting all output (stdout and/or stderr) to, for instance, '/dev/null" (It's been years since I worked with UNIX.) The program doesn't need to know anything about such redirections being made by the shell. (The shell IS the "wrapper function" for any executable you launch from the command line.)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to wrap `std::cout`. Instead you should create a *sink stream*, i.e. an output stream that discards all output given to it. You then pass either `cout` or your sink stream to the functions that generate your output. Creating a sink stream is fairly easy to do.

```
#include <ostream>
#include <streambuf>

class SinkBuffer : public std::streambuf
{
};

class SinkStream : public std::ostream
{
public:
    SinkStream() : std::ostream(&buffer) {}
private:
    SinkBuffer buffer;
};
```

Then you might use it like this

```
static void output(std::ostream& out)
{
    out << "hello world\n";
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    if (argc >= 2 && strcmp(argv[1], "-q") == 0)
    {
        SinkStream ss;
        output(ss);
    }
    else
    {
        output(std::cout);
    }
}
```

This program looks for the command line argument `-q` and if it finds it uses the sink stream, otherwise it uses `std::cout`. The effect is that if no command line arguments are passed then the program prints `hello world` but if `-q` is passed then it prints nothing.